# Протокол передачи данных через сокет

Tags: сеть, сокеты, java

Проектирую протокол передачи. Это могут быть строчки, а могут быть и файлы.
 Я читал, что можно так: Передаем массив байтов, первые 4 байта будут характеризовать содержимое: строчка, файл и т.д.

Вот как примерно я представляю это себе:

```
public void run()
        {
          input  = ClientSocket.getInputStream();
          byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];

          while(true)
          {
            while ((readen = in.read(buffer))!=-1)
              {
               String line = new String(buffer, 0, readen, serverInfo.getEncoding());
              }
              buffer = null;
          }
        }
```

В данном куске кода нет выделения первых 4х байт,тут стандартно передается строка(пример взял на просторах сети).

Интересует такой вопрос:

Вот этот кусок кода все пакеты будет принимать или только первый?

```
while ((readen = in.read(buffer))!=-1)
```

Буду рад выслушать советы по организации протокола

Comment: Очередное "во первых".

--

Во первых, в протоколе TCP (это им вы пользуетесь) на уровне прикладной программы понятия **пакет** не существует. 

Существует **поток** байт, который может "разрезаться" (на куски, которые Вы считываете в буфер) **произвольным** образом. 

Действительно, обычно длина порции данных принимаемой в буфер, соответствует длине отправленных за один вызов данных. Но не всегда.

Это источник "непонятных" ошибок в программе, которые трудно воспроизводятся.

Надеюсь, осознание данного факта поможет Вам правильно скорректировать алгоритм (Ваш прикладной протокол обмена).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Голову не ломайте сделайте себе класс-структуру, типа:

```
public class MyProtocol {
   private byte[4] descriptor;
   private int chunk_length;
   private String chunk;

   MyProtocol() {
       //blah-blah
   }
}
```

Далее упакуйте все это безобразие в виде JSON строки или если бережете байты, то в виде Java объектов через `DataOutputStream()` и отправляйте на ту сторону.

На той стороне читаем байтики перекидываем их в объект через десериализацию JSON строки (ну или через `DataInputStream` - если отправили через `DataOutputStream`). В итоге на выходе вы получите свой класс/объект `MyProtocol` - ну и работайте с ним дальше.

Можно похитрее, разбить передаваемую структуру на несколько объектов/классов - ну в общем вы поняли суть.

Comment: JSON - да, бинарная сериализация - строгое нет.

Comment: Ну почему же нет, если надо экономить траффик, то бинарная сериализация самое оно

Comment: потому что бинарная сериализация приносит одни проблемы.

 - сменилась версия - не факт, что она будет точно так же работать
 - понадобилось написать клиент или сервер на другом языке - проблема.
 - если что то пошло не так и нужно смотреть тсп дампы - прострация обеспечена.


уж лучше использовать xml, чем бинарную сериализацию. Хотя сам по себе xml слишком перегружен.

Я  не против бинарной сериализации в виде bson или protobuf - они хорошо стандартизированы (bson не очень, но он и прост) и любого желающего можно быстро отправить читать спеку.

Comment: Да ну в фтопку XML - это надо писать парсер, генерировать его замаешься - опять же оверхед неоправданно высок. JSON милое дело.

Comment: во всех нормальных языках в стандартной библиотеке есть уже поддержка XML. потому в плане переносимости XML - самое оно. можно, как вариант, написать свой сериализатор, но тогда нужно будет его же писать и на других языках, участвующих в разработке. но он так же избавляет кодеров от проблем, описанных в комменте, да и при правильном подходе, его реализация не так страшна.

Comment: Попробуйте сначала JSON и почувствуйте разницу...

Comment: XML очень тяжелый (я бы даже сказал - дурацкий) формат. Почему он стал популярным - вообще загадка. 

Видимо XML изначально был поддержан корпорациями, а о всех форматах типа JSON реально пишущие люди никак договориться не могли.

Answer (score 2):

Конкретный ответ на вопрос.

Этот кусок кода  будет принимать все байты, порциями произвольной длины от 1 байта до размера буфера (без учета пакетов), пока сокет не закроют на передачу (или вообще не закроют).

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, 4 байта для различения строчка/файл - это слишком много. Во вторых, в первую очередь надо продумать как различать тип сообщения, а строчка/файл - это уже параметры сообщения.

Чем заново изобретать велосипед, воспользуйтесь готовой библиотекой, где все изначальные вопросы уже решены, например, [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).